# How do you iterate through a List from a DTO in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, data-binding, thymeleaf

My project uses Spring Boot with JPA, MySQL and Thymeleaf. I can't seem to iterate inside the view through a list of objects stored inside a DTO which is passed as a model attribute to the view.

Here is the relevant bit of the DTO:

```
public class Form {
    private SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel();
    private List<Cities> listOfCities;
//......getters and setters
}
```

Here is the Cities model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Cities")
public class Cities {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_city;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_country")
    private Countries id_country;
//getters and setters
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/simple")
public String simpleGet(Model model) {
    Form form = new Form();
    form.setCities(citiesService.all());
    model.addAttribute("form", form);
    return "simple";
}
```

And finally, here is the view:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/simple}" method="POST" th:object="${form}">
 <input type="text"  th:field="*{simpleModel.userName}">
 <select name="id_city">
   <option th:each="city : ${listOfCities}" th:value="${city.id_city}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit"  value="Assign">
</form>
```

I have checked inside the controller after "form.setCities(citiesService.all());" by printing to the console in a for loop and the data is there, however in the view, I don't get anything, the select list is empty with no option elements. How can I access the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs to have the list of cities.  You can add the `listOfCities` to the model before your return statement:

`model.addAttribute("listOfCities", form.getListOfCities());`

Aside:

- Include some default text within the option tag.  When you load the page in a browser (and not on a container/server), you can see how it would display.  This is a major reason to use Thymeleaf.
- Pretty hard to tell what you're doing based on your naming convention.  Is `Cities` a list of cities?  Because you have a String for `name`, so something seems like it's not named correctly.   You may want to change it to just `City` and `id`.  Then your methods become `getCity().getId()` instead of `getCities().getId_city()`.  Same would go for `Countries`.
- Avoid EAGER if you can

Alternatively, look at using `@Data` and `@Builder` from Project Lombok.